# Item click event detection in flex datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

The data grid is defined below with a data provider of xmllist type:

```
   <mx:columns>         
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="ans1" headerText="ans1"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="ans2" headerText="ans2"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="ans3" headerText="ans3"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="ans4" headerText="ans4"/>
    </mx:columns>
```

On item click event i need to obtain the data(the text) associated to the current column in use. I have tried the following:

```
 private function itemClickEvent(event:ListEvent):void {                
            var selected:String = event.currentTarget.selectedItem;
            debug2.text = selected;
        }
```

But, the debug label text displays the xmllist:

```
  <question><ans1>a</ans1>...<ans4>d</ans4></question>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this code:

```
//
var grid: DataGrid = event.currentTarget as DataGrid;
//
debug2.text = grid.selectedItem[(grid.columns[event.columnIndex] as DataGridColumn).dataField];
```

This is just a concept to show how to get the data from individual column.